# Generating a Gamma centered uniform k mesh in SIESTA DFT

Tags: density-functional-theory, k-points, siesta, brillouin-zone

The SIESTA DFT software provides to incorporate a [Monkhorst-Pack k grid](https://siesta-project.org/SIESTA_MATERIAL/Docs/Manuals/siesta-4.1.5.pdf#siesta-pos-78-kgrid.MonkhorstPack) in DFT calculations. However to use the results with the BoltzTraP2 software, a Gamma centered k-grid with uniform distribution is required. Has anyone had any experience with this kind of a problem for 1D and 2D systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The siesta kgrid specification looks like this:

```
%block kgrid.MonkhorstPack
  <int> <int> <int> <offset>
  <int> <int> <int> <offset>
  <int> <int> <int> <offset>
%endblock kgrid.MonkhorstPack
```

What $\Gamma$ centered means is that the offsets are all $0.$.
For some systems it may be beneficial to use non-centered grids to reduce the total number of k-points due to symmetries. However, if BoltzTraP2 requires the $\Gamma$ centered variant, simply do as above and set `<offset>` to $0.$ for each direction.

Here an example with `NA, NB, NC` being the number of k-points along each reciprocal lattice vector:

```
%block kgrid.MonkhorstPack
  NA 0 0 0.
  0 NB 0 0.
  0 0 NC 0.
%endblock kgrid.MonkhorstPack
```

For details related to their meaning see [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2238/887).

Comment: To avoid things getting too long, this discussion has been moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59299306#59299306)